# Mysql - Select - como agrupar dois valores diferentes em um único valor

Tags: mysql, query, select, if, concatenação-de-string

Gostaria de ajuda em um assunto.

Possuo uma query que lista pedidos(ordens), e cada pedido tem seu status, exemplo: 'confirmado', 'recusado' e 'naoconfirmado', gostaria de criar um Select que una esses status, por exemplo, 'confirmado' é um status, 'recusado' e 'naoconfirmado' como sendo um único status, ou seja, uma forma de agrupar dois valores diferentes em um único

Query:

```
SELECT monthname(o.processed_timestamp) AS Mês,
       o.status,
       count(1)
FROM orders_received.partner_commerce_item o
WHERE o.status IN ('confirmado',
                   'recusado',
                   'naoconfirmado')
GROUP BY month(o.processed_timestamp),
         o.status;
```

Da forma que está será listado os pedidos em três status diferentes, queria criar algo do tipo:

```
SELECT monthname(o.processed_timestamp) AS Mês,
       o.status,
       count(1)
FROM orders_received.partner_commerce_item o
WHERE o.status = 'confirmado'
OR    o.status in ('recusado','naoconfirmado') as recusados                   
GROUP BY month(o.processed_timestamp),
         o.status;
```

Porém dessa forma apresenta erro de sintaxe

Testei de várias formas e não encontrei nenhuma que funcione, se tiverem alguma ideia de como fazer isso, seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Você consegue resolver essa consulta utilizando o operador CASE ou IF
Segue um exemplo:

CASE

```
Create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100), status varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title, status) values(1, "Hello1", "nok");
insert into Test(id, title, status) values(2, "Hello2", "pen");
insert into Test(id, title, status) values(3, "Hello3", "ok");
insert into Test(id, title, status) values(4, "Hello4", "ok");

select 
    case 
        when status in ('pen', 'ok') then 'confirmado'
        when status in ('nok') then 'rejeitado'
    end statusAgrupado, 
    count(*) 
from 
    Test
group by
    case 
        when status in ('pen', 'ok') then 'confirmado'
        when status in ('nok') then 'rejeitado'
 end;
```

IF

```
 create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100), status varchar(100));
 insert into Test(id, title, status) values(1, "Hello1", "nok");
 insert into Test(id, title, status) values(2, "Hello2", "pen");
 insert into Test(id, title, status) values(3, "Hello3", "ok");
 insert into Test(id, title, status) values(4, "Hello4", "ok");

 select 
     if( status in ('pen', 'ok') , 'confirmado', 'rejeitado' ) statusAgrupado,
     count(1) total
 from
     Test
 group by
     if( status in ('pen', 'ok') , 'confirmado', 'rejeitado' );
```

Eu testei esse codigo no site

CASE: https://paiza.io/projects/ZltxTfYL9aliDxRjztpqHg?language=mysql

IF: https://paiza.io/projects/FF9ol7IODRZkvs-3NZP_qg?language=mysql

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Bacco

Comment: Obrigado!!

Funcionou lindo utilizando o IF.

obs: lembrando que precisei colocar o if no group by também (assim como no exemplo que você colocou), só ressaltando caso alguém precise fazer algo parecido

Answer (score 0):

Veja se atende:

```
SELECT monthname(o.processed_timestamp) AS Mês,
       SUM(CASE o.status = 'confirmado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS confirmado;
       SUM(o.status ='recusado' OR o.status = 'naoconfirmado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recusados
FROM orders_received.partner_commerce_item o
GROUP BY month(o.processed_timestamp),
         o.status;
```